# How do I create a production build of a typescript monorepo application that is compatible with an Azure Function App?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions, monorepo

I am trying to wrap my head around typescript [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) and how they are intended to be used in a production build, specifically for an Azure Function App.
I am not using any functionality for monorepos at the package manager level, like npm workspaces or lerna. I do not want to publish any packages to npm.

I guess the main problem I have is that I want my compiled output from typescript to be in a folder structure that is compatible with the [conventions of an Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#folder-structure), while having a different structure for the non-compiled projects. I am using es6 modules and the file references for the imports will be wrong if the folder stucture of the project changes.

Lets pretend that we have the following folder structure:

```
ts-monorepo
   packages
      myApp
         GetHello
            function.json   <-- Azure Function App specific file
            index.ts
         host.json          <-- Azure Function App specific file
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
      myLib
         lib
            greeter.ts
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
```

`myApp` wants to use `myLib` and hence `packages/myApp/GetHello/index.ts` has the following line in it:

```
// packages/myApp/GetHello/index.ts
import { sayHello } from '../../myLib/lib/greeter';
```

(The above should probably be using tsconfig [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) property to make an "alias" for the lib, but I don't think that is important for the problem I am about to describe).

If I specify that I want both projects to use a `dist` directory for the typescript output, then the compiled files would end up under a different file path than is specified in the imports, which creates errors because of that the referenced files are not found.

After the compilation:

```
ts-monorepo
   packages
      myApp
         dist       <-- new folder from typescript compilation
            GetHello
               function.json
               index.js   <-- In file: import { sayHello } from '../../myLib/lib/greeter'; // gives error
            host.json
         GetHello
            function.json
            index.ts
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
      myLib
         dist       <-- new folder from typescript compilation
            lib
               greeter.js
         lib
            greeter.ts
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
```

This would mean that it is important to keep the same folder structure after the compilation?
So I guess it would be an option to specify in both projects `tsconfig.json` that the `outDir` should be the original folder names, but inside of a new common e.g `build` folder?

```
// tsconfig.json for myApp
{
   ...
   "outDir": "../build/myApp"
}
```

and

```
// tsconfig.json for myLib
{
   ...
   "outDir": "../build/myLib"
}
```

Ending up in that all output is placed in the build folder:

```
ts-monorepo
   packages
      build                 <-- new typescript generated folder
         myApp
            host.json
            GetHello
               function.json
               index.js     <-- Now import { sayHello } from '../../myLib/lib/greeter'; is correct.
         myLib
            lib
               greeter.js
      myApp
         GetHello
            function.json
            index.ts
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
      myLib
         lib
            greeter.ts
         package.json
         tsconfig.json
```

**Combining the output with Azure Function App conventions**

If I somehow get the `node_modules` into the folders as well and if this would be a normal Node.js  application, then `node packages/build/myApp/GetHello/index.js` would run locally, but it is not going to work as an Azure Function App. This is because by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#folder-structure) you need to have the `host.json` file in the root of the folder that gets deployed as a Function App and all functions needs to be folders that are direct children to that root folder. I basically need to deploy the `build/myApp` folder to the Function App, but then I cannot have `myLib` outside. And if I move `myLib` into `myApp` I need to rewrite all of the imports of files inside of `myApp`.

I have been thinking about maybe moving or combining the approach with some monorepo package level tools like `npm workspaces` but the ones that I have looked at works by creating symbolic links. Those links will still point to folders outside of the `myApp` folder and hence be broken after the deploy. ( [Similar to this](https://2ality.com/2021/07/simple-monorepos.html))

If anyone knows or have a suggestion on how to solve this scenario it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Iv'e come up against the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution/workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on it, I had this exact problem and ended up creating an [Azure Functions plugin for NX workspaces](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nxazure/func).
You are welcome to use it as well, if you need to.
It basically abstracts the entire process of what you've described and allows you to use TS config paths and if you need to publish, there is a publish executor that does the job for you.